# Issue with Composer Updating Laravel to 6

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8, laravel-6

So, I've been trying to run composer update in an attempt to update my Laravel version from 5.8 to ^6.0. Every attempt has failed, with an error message of this or similar to this:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove adldap2/adldap2 v8.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install adldap2/adldap2 v8.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install adldap2/adldap2 v8.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install adldap2/adldap2 v8.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install adldap2/adldap2 v8.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install adldap2/adldap2 v8.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.17.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.17.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.15.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.15.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.14.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.13.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.13.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.12.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.11.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.10.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.10.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.1
    - Installation request for adldap2/adldap2 ^8.1 -> satisfiable by adldap2/adldap2[v8.1.0, v8.1.1, v8.1.2, v8.1.3, v8.1.4, v8.1.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
    - adldap2/adldap2 v8.1.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.39], illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.0.x-dev
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8
    - don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v5.6.39].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.10.1, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v6.9.0].
```

My composer.json file is set up as so:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.28",
        "adldap2/adldap2": "^8.1",
        "adldap2/adldap2-laravel": "^4.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
          "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I'm at a loss of what's causing this to fail, is there a section I'm leaving out of the .json file or improperly listing my requirements?

Comment: Did you tried reading the error log? `adldap2/adldap2` package requires laravel 5 and you are installing 6. Try checking if `adldap2/adldap2` have a new version that supports laravel 6.

Comment: Changing to version 5.8.* fixed the issue, thank you so much, I'm not sure why that didn't stick out to me!

Answer (score 1):

As you can read on the [package page for `adldap2/adldap2`](https://packagist.org/packages/adldap2/adldap2#v8.1.5), the given version 8.1.5 is not compatible with Laravel 6. You need at least v10.1.0.

The next package to be upgrade is `adldap2/adldap2-laravel` - currently, you restricted this package to v4, but this is no longer compatible with the package you've updated from above. Restrict this one to `adldap2/adldap2-laravel:^6.0`. And as this requires the other package, you can skip the dependency on `adldap2/adldap2` altogether